# RewriteRule and lack of reference

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$              index.php?page=$1   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$     index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2    [QSA,L]
```

it works fine with

```
http://localhost/account
```

but when I use

```
http://localhost/account/settings
```

CSS isn't applicable. With first link, the page is CSSed correctly, with the second link - the page is white as if there's no CSS, containing simple text generated by index.php?page=account&subpage=settings.

What's the problem?

Comment: Which URLs are used for CSS in these pages?

Comment: What do you mean? You can clearly see that the call for all pages and subpages goes through index.php (it's using SMARTY, refering to page_index.tpl and, in this, <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to your usage of relative links in css/js/image file. You have 2 ways to fix it:

1. Just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. OR else try adding this in your page's HTML header:

   ```
   <base href="/" />
   ```